# code for showing comments from multiple comment boxes to a single iframe facebook page?

Tags: facebook, comments

Ive installed a facebook comment box on a php product page on our website. This means the comment box is displayed on all our product pages

Im using

```
data-href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"
```

as the url to comment on so the urls posted to facebook are the ones the user has commented on.

I'm now trying to display all the comments from the php product page on our website to an iframe tab in facebook.

I've tried adding various different codes to the iframe:

```
<fb:activity 
site="fmysite"
app_id="myappid">
</fb:activity>
```

and

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=mykey
```

and various other urls but I cant get all the comments to show in the iframe.

If I put a single url from one of the product pages with comments on it, it works fine. But thats not what im trying to achieve.

Is there any way to do this pls?

In the comment moderation tool, all the comments from all the product pages are shown, what is the code that is showing all the comments there? Can I use that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't do that.

You can probably put more than one comment plugin in that page, one per product or something like that, but it's probably not what you're looking for.

Another approach would be to create it yourself.
Using [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql) you can fetch the comments for all products (using the urls) and then you can simply display them.
The problem is that you'll have to sort them and render the display yourself.

To get the comments with FQL you'll need to use the [comment table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) and the [link_stat table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/), and do something like this per product url:

```
SELECT username, text
FROM comment
WHERE object_id IN
    (SELECT comments_fbid
    FROM link_stat
    WHERE url ="PRODUCT_URL")
```

You can of course select more/different fields, read about your options in the *comment* table documentation.

You can do that either in the client side using the [*FB.api*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) method (of the [js sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript)) or from the server side by issuing http requests to:

> https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=FQL_QUERY

Just keep in mind that you need an active access_token and maybe one or more permissions (check the docs).